# One time actions in Chrome API

Tags: api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension for Chrome as a browser action. I need to know if there is any way to  have some functions executed while installing the app. All of the pages that I have seen like "background" and "popup" execute everytime. I need to configure the extension and then use these parameters further in my extension. 
Is there a way to do so or I will have to put a check everytime the browser starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use a background page and `localStorage`. Each time the background page starts check if `localStorage.getItem('installed') === 'true'` to see if it is a new istall or not.

Background pages start when Chrome starts vs browser action popups that start every time a user clicks the button.

Comment: i found it after roaming around the api pages for a while. It was listed in FAQ, i dont think thats right place to put this information though. But anyway thanks a lot.